# PHP int typecasting generating wrong value

Tags: php, type-conversion

I want to store integer value in database, and for that im using (int) type casting on $_POST values. But its evaluating another value instead of submitted integers.

```
echo (int)0444444;
```

outputs

```
149796
```

Please help.

Comment: `0444444` is already an integer, casting is doing nothing here; you simply chose to write it in octal (base 8) notation, rather than the more usual decimal (base 10) notation.

Comment: Note that you mention "*using (int) type casting on $_POST values*" yet your example uses an integer. `$_POST` values are always *strings* unless you manually change them.

Comment: Good point, i didn't notice that in example..but actually i was getting weird values in my form processing using int typecasting on $_POST.

Comment: You've edited your question - it now has a completely different meaning. In 32-bit PHP, the maximum int is `2147483647`

Comment: REVIEW NOTE: A couple minutes ago I misunderstood the reason of the edit, so I have also placed back together with the edit what I saw the original. (In the review we don't see full history.) Sorry, that I was wrong, went back to Ian's suggestions. Regards.

Answer (score 7):

Prefixing an integer with `0` means it should be interpreted as an **octal** value, that is, base 8 instead of base 10.

```
0444444 (OCT) = 149796 (DEC)
```

If you want to convert a string to an integer, instead of casting, you can use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) which optionally will allow you to specify base 10.

The cast in your example though is a cast from an int to an int (0444444 already being interpreted as an integer), so your cast is a no-op.

Comment: Thanks but echo intval('03894563333', 10); still evaluating another value...

Comment: @TPSstar In 32-bit PHP, the maximum int is `2147483647`

Comment: @TPSstar Since you're running on a 32-bit platform, the maximum possible int value is 2147483647 (`PHP_INT_MAX` for 32 bit platforms), the conversion works well on 64-bit PHP and returns the expected result. If you need numbers larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`, you need to use another datatype than integer.

Answer (score 3):

As per the other answers, the `0` prefix causes PHP to interpret the value as Octal.

The [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: intval also evaluating it as octal :)

Comment: Are you sure? `print intval('04444444');` = `4444444`. You could always explicitly state base 10 like this: `print intval('04444444',10);`

Comment: echo intval('03894563333', 10); is evaluating another value.

Comment: In 32-bit PHP, the maximum int is `2147483647`

Answer (score 2):

Values with a leading `0` are treated as octal values.

Comment: Thank you, so which kind of typecasting would work? or do i need to use is_int() ?

Comment: @TPSstar: Just remove the `0`.

Comment: But still that's not the solution, i need something which should work in any case even with zeros :)